# Custom adapter for ListView (only 1 ImageView being displayed)

Tags: java, android, listview

For some reason my custom adapter is only allowing me to have 1 image visible in the list view at any time, I am not sure why this is happening. There should be a image within each list item but only the last list item has its image set, so I assume I am re-using a value somewhere that I should not be. The rest of the list items are being set properly.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private ArrayList<Item> itemList;
    private ViewHolder holder; 
    private Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> list) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        this.itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        this.itemList.addAll(list);
        this.context = context;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView img;
        TextView name;
        CheckBox access;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_grid, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.access = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 

        else { holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); }

        Item it = itemList.get(position);

        new UrlLookup().execute(it.getUrl());
        holder.name.setText(it.getName());
        holder.access.setChecked(it.isSelected());

        return convertView;
    }

    //Create an image from the url passed in from the server and display it on the image view   
    private class UrlLookup extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
        Bitmap bmp;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params){  
            try {
                URL u = new URL(params[0]);
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(u.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            return "Done!";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);    
            holder.img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A tip here. No need to get the LayoutInflater every time `getView` gets called. Move the `LayoutInflater` initialization to your constructor.

Comment: @tolgap Thanks I did that, issue still remains though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting the fact that your holder changes every time a view is visible. So it's normal only the last item has an image.

AsyncTask will take considerably longer to finish than your `getView` method.

You should pass your ImageView to your AsyncTask:

```
new UrlLookup().execute(it.getUrl(), holder.img);
```

To call the AsyncTask

```
private class UrlLookup extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, String>{
    Bitmap bmp;
    ImageView view;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params){ 
        view = (ImageView) params[1]; 
        try {
            URL u = new URL((String)params[0]);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(u.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return "Done!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);    
        view.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```

Now you will have a reference of the ImageView of every row in every AsyncTask.

I would like to point out to you that Koush has a splendid project for doing just what you want:
[UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper)